# Which philosophers have touched on whether or not something is moral if it is commanded by a deity?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

I'll explain further: if a deity tells you something is moral, is that truly moral? Which philosophers have touched on that specific topic?

Comment: We have a sense of what is moral because God has given us that sense. There is no other possible source for a moral standard, so what God commands is moral because He is good and has the authority to designate what is moral.

Comment: I look nonsensical rhetoric and propaganda as much as the next guy, but that doesn't address the question I asked.

Comment: And if you say "there can be no other possible source for a moral standard," then you've simply failed to read the major critics of religion and, more specifically, theology; wherein it is argued pretty effectively that no only are there moral standards without god, but there isn't a moral standard _with_ god. It is not moral to do something because you are told to do it; and, even if it was, which it is not, you would have to prove that _your_ god and _your_ text is the correct version, which you obviously could not do.

Comment: I think it does address the question: I it truly moral? Yes, because God has the authority to determine what is moral.

Comment: The atheist only has one tool in his toolbox to explain the existence of any biological property, namely, natural selection. Not only can it not account for moral standards, there is no non-circular way to account for the *origin* of any standard of value whatsoever. At best it could explain why such standards didn't get killed off, which doesn't address the question of origin at all.

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthyphro_dilemma relevant?

Comment: @Veedrac That's damned perfect. I completely forgot about the book. And I've been on a Plato spree lately.

Comment: @PédeLeão You see, we philosophers have to actually work toward what is morally good and acceptable. We don't lazily say "God told us to," and we don't lazier still say that "God exists because we don't know things." We're more intellectually honest than that. Circular logic defining origin? The first cause is arguably the stupidest argument ever made. Who created God? "God did!" That's so circular that straight doesn't even exist in the conscious at that point. And if you think it was moral when God commanded the entire murder of a village, and the rape of the slave women, then kudos, brother

Comment: It's worth noting that a lot of this is going to vary by culture; whereas gods are typically thought of perfect and perfectly moral in Judeo-Christian cultures, many others have openly amoral and immoral gods.

Comment: @Veedrac That's very true. Hindu comes to mind somewhat quickly, and Greek Mythology certainly had its share of unvirtuous Gods. But the arguments, generally speaking, should be useful. And almost all religions have a character at the top of the structure who is, while morally ambiguous sometimes, supposed to be the definition of morality (i.e., even if the god does something horrible by our view, it is still moral, because it cannot be, by definition, immoral). But I'm basing that on my understanding of 7-8 religions, and I certainly don't know the other few thousand who may have evil gods.

Comment: @user31078. Considering the sinfulness of mankind and the fact that we deserve nothing more than eternal torment, God would have been just if He had destroyed us long ago. But He didn't! And not only that, but He also sent Jesus to die for the sins of His people, so of course I believe that God is just, good and merciful. God deserves all of our thanks and our praise!

Comment: @PédeLeão At this point you're either sarcastic, or a sadist. I'm concerned about the latter, but I won't make a fuss of it. It would be telling of the average theological mind if one truly believe that man is not only born in sin, but inherently destined for the worst of torments. What a lazy God who is so useless in his powers that he cannot control himself to forgive the natural way, but must torture a good man to death. Ah, I concede, the sadistic and twisted minds won't be swayed. Christianity is a sadist's religion.

Comment: Ayn Rand has proposed objective rational ethics, which works splendidly without any supernatural elements. The "good" is that, which promotes the life of a man as a rational being and the "bad" is that, which separates a man from his full life as a rational being. Thus, morality comes from facts of objective reality and it's also a necessity for a man, if he wishes to live and if he pursuits happiness. Conversely if he does not wan't to live or pursuits happiness he does not need a guideline for his actions and nature (and society) will take it's course.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a number have done so, and there is a revived interest in the topic. You might try :

Daniel M. Johnson, 'The Objectivity of Obligations in Divine Motivation Theory', The Journal of Religious Ethics, Vol. 40, No. 3 (September 2012), pp. 504-517

Thomas M. Osborne Jr., 'Ockham as a Divine-Command Theorist', Religious Studies, Vol. 41, No. 1 (Mar., 2005), pp. 1-22.

C. Stephen Evans, Kierkegaard's Ethic of Love: Divine Commands and Moral Requirements. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2004.

Mark Murphy, An Essay on Divine Authority. Ithaca, N.Y.: Cornell University Press, 2002

John Hare, God's Call: Moral Realism, God's Commands, and Human Autonomy. Grand Rapids, Mich.: Eerdmans, 2001

Richard J. Mouw, The God Who Commands (Notre Dame: University of Notre Dame
Press, 1990.

Philip L. Quinn, "An Argument for Divine Command Ethics," Christian Theism and
the Problems of Philosophy, ed. M. Beaty (Notre Dame: University of Notre Dame
Press, 1990).

Edward R. Wierenga, The Nature of God,  God (Ithaca and London: Cornell University Press, 1989

Philip L. Quinn, "Divine Command Ethics: A Causal Theory," Divine Command
Morality: Historical and Contemporary Readings, ed. Janine M. Idziak (New York
and Toronto: Edwin Mellen Press, 1979).

Philip L. Quinn, Divine Commands and Moral Requirements (Oxford: Clarendon
Press, 1978).

Baruch A. Brody, "Morality and Religion Reconsidered," Readings in the Philosophy of Religion, ed. B. A. Brody (Englewood Cliffs: Prentice-Hall, 1974).

Alvin Plantinga, God, Freedom, and Evil (New York: Harper & Row, 1974.

With any luck you'll find useful material here.